# Returning Multiple Variables with isset()

Tags: php, return, isset

I have a bit of code that returns the user agent, running it through a function to parse it.  The code I have previously used returns only one variable from the parsing function (there are three: 'platform' 'browser' 'version'):

```
function my_get_user_agent($value)
{
$browser = parse_user_agent();
return isset($browser['platform']) ? $browser['platform'] : '';
}
```

While this code works to return the platform of the user agent, I need to append it to return all three variables in the function.  I changed the first half of the code to what I assume is correct:

```
return isset($browser['platform'], $browser['browser'], $browser['version'])? $browser['platform'] : '';
```

I am unsure, however, as to what I need to do to properly return all three values.  Suggestions?

Comment: Create an array with key/value pairs for the three elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return the entire array:

```
return $browser;
```

Then access the values later:

```
$browser['platform'];
$browser['browser'];
$browser['version'];
```

Reading your question again, you seem to want to ensure the value are set. You can do this:

```
foreach($browser as $value) {
    if(isset($value)) {
        $data[] = $value;
    }
}
return $data;
```

Now data will contain platform, browser, and version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tuple structure in PHP: [Are there tuples in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083760/are-there-tuples-in-php)

You can either return the whole browser array, or a subset like this (this will not return the undefined values):

```
array_intersect_key($browser, array_flip(array("platform", "browser", "version")))
```

Also, if you want to set the result of your function to variables, the `list` construct can be handy, but you have to be sure that the values are in that order and that they exist. For that you would have to proceed like SeanWM suggested:

```
function my_get_user_agent($agent) {
  $browser = parse_user_agent($agent);
  foreach(array("platform", "browser", "version") as $value) {
      $data[] = isset($browser[$value]) ? $browser[$value] : '';
  }
  return $data;
}

list($platform, $browser, $version) = my_get_user_agent($agent);
```